# Checking if you can log into an email account using php?

Tags: php

I am writing a bit more at the top in an effort to get it to post. Skip this and read on:

I am writing a script that tests user's e-mail accouns. For example, the user might provide an e-mail address such as: johnny@bla.com. For the purpose of this exercise, I know that the domain name will be: mail.domain.com. So, in this case, mail.bla.com. The password is provided by the user, because they enter it to test the account.

I need to know:

- If the user entered an incorrect password
- If they could reach the server

It must just be able to check POP email accounts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this PHP class that allows you to access POP3 e-mails

http://www.phpclasses.org/package/2-PHP-Access-to-e-mail-mailboxes-using-the-POP3-protocol.html